# Get certain percentile values over SQL table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table storing users, the number of red balls they have, the total number of balls (blue, yellow, other colors etc.), and the ratio of red to total balls.

Schema looks like this:

```
**user_id** | **ratio** | **red_balls** | **total_balls**
     1            .2             2              10
     2            .3             6              20
```

I want to select the 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100 percentile values based on ordering the **red_balls** column, so this doesn't mean I want the 0, 0.25, etc. values for the ratio column. I want the 25th percentile of the **red_balls** column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do what you want:

```
select *
from your_table
where ratio in (0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
order by red_balls
```

Query finds all rows with `ratio`s that exactly one of 0, 25, 50, 75, 100 and sort rows in ascending order by count of `red_ball`s

Comment: Just edited the question, I want the 25th etc percentile of the red_balls column, not the ratio column.